# Filtering AMI by name using aws-cli

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, aws-cli

Is there a way to filter public AMIs that contain a particular string (say `abcd`)?

The command:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters Name=name,Values=abcd
```

returns only those AMIs that exactly match `Name=abcd`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [Listing and Filtering Using the CLI and API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Filtering.html#Filtering_Resources_CLI):

> You can also use wildcards with the filter values. An asterisk (*) matches zero or more characters, and a question mark (?) matches exactly one character.

List any RHEL 7.*x* HVM GA images

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters Name=name,Values=RHEL-7.?_HVM_GA*
```

Comment: Note: It must be `Name=name` and not `Name=Name` as this answer states; which is odd since if you run a `describe-images` it seems like it would be the other way around.